# Increasing productivity | What commands am I repeating?

Tags: windows, developer-tools

I'm looking for a programming that monitors my activity in Windows Vista/XP/2003 that lets me know what commands, shortcuts, web sites, etc. I visit more frequently.

with this information I could create shortcuts, hotkeys, aliases, etc to increase productivity, as time goes on I could know how much time I saved in comparison to other days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Slife](http://www.slifelabs.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Leon Bambrick's time snapper is pretty interesting. May not be exactly what your looking for though. http://www.timesnapper.com/

Answer (score 3):

There's a program called [Rescue Time](http://www.rescuetime.com/) which monitors your applications and website usage.

Answer (score 1):

I have a program like that and have used it for years. It's called *laziness*. When I get tired enough of doing the same thing over again, I write a program or script to do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a tool to record your activity, but [Tasktop](http://tasktop.com/products/tour/) might help you achieve what you want.

I use Mylyn, Tasktop little bother, in eclipse to organize and keep me focused in my tasks, and it's a great help.